# I'm trying to count all letters in a txt file then display in descending order

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, display

As the title says:

So far this is where I'm at my code does work however I am having trouble displaying the information in order. Currently it just displays the information randomly.

```
def frequencies(filename):
    infile=open(filename, 'r')
    wordcount={}
    content = infile.read()
    infile.close()
    counter = {}
    invalid = "‘'`,.?!:;-_\n—' '"

    for word in content:
        word = content.lower()
        for letter in word:
            if letter not in invalid:
                if letter not in counter:
                    counter[letter] = content.count(letter)
                    print('{:8} appears {} times.'.format(letter, counter[letter]))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying in descending order needs to be outside your search-loop otherwise they will be displayed as they are encountered.

Sorting in descending order is quite easy using the built-in [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) (you'll need to set the `reverse`-argument!)

However python is *batteries included* and there is already a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). So it could be as simply as:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

def frequencies(filename):
    # Sets are especially optimized for fast lookups so this will be
    # a perfect fit for the invalid characters.
    invalid = set("‘'`,.?!:;-_\n—' '")

    # Using open in a with block makes sure the file is closed afterwards.
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:  
        # The "char for char ...." is a conditional generator expression
        # that feeds all characters to the counter that are not invalid.
        counter = Counter(char for char in infile.read().lower() if char not in invalid)

    # If you want to display the values:
    for char, charcount in sorted(counter.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
        print(char, charcount)
```

The Counter already has a `most_common` method but you want to display all characters and counts so it's not a good fit in this case. However if you only want to know the x most common counts then it would suitable.

Answer (score 5):

Dictionaries are unordered data structures. Also if you want to count some items within a set of data you better to use [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which is more optimized and pythonic for this aim.

Then you can just use `Counter.most_common(N)` in order to print most `N` common items within your Counter object.

Also regarding the opening of files, you can simply use the `with` statement that closes the file at the end of the block automatically. And it's better to not print the final result inside your function instead, you can make your function a generator by yielding the intended lines and then printing them when even you want.

```
from collections import Counter

def frequencies(filename, top_n):
    with open(filename) as infile:
        content = infile.read()
    invalid = "‘'`,.?!:;-_\n—' '"
    counter = Counter(filter(lambda x: not invalid.__contains__(x), content))
    for letter, count in counter.most_common(top_n):
        yield '{:8} appears {} times.'.format(letter, count)
```

Then use a for loop in order to iterate over the generator function:

```
for line in frequencies(filename, 100):
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to iterate over 'words', and then over letters in them. When you iterate over a string (like `content`), you will already have single chars (length 1 strings). Then, you would want to wait untill after your counting loop before showing output. After counting, you could manually sort:

```
for letter, count in sorted(counter.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
    # do stuff
```

However, better use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

content = filter(lambda x: x not in invalid, content)
c = Counter(content)
for letter, count in c.most_common():  # descending order of counts
    print('{:8} appears {} times.'.format(letter, number))
# for letter, number in c.most_common(n):  # limit to n most
#     print('{:8} appears {} times.'.format(letter, count))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your dictionary at the time you print, with the `sorted` method:

```
lettercount = {}
invalid = "‘'`,.?!:;-_\n—' '"
infile = open('text.file')
for c in infile.read().lower():
    if c not in invalid:
        lettercount[c] = lettercount.setdefault(c,0) + 1
for letter in sorted(lettercount):
    print("{} appears {} times".format(letter,lettercount[letter]))
```

Rmq: I used `setdefault` change method to set the default value to 0 when we meet a letter for the first time